# Run process and get its ID in Windows 7

Tags: java, windows, linux, shell, process

In my java project I need to run VLC Media Player (for steaming) and on request I want to stop streaming.
In Linux, I have created following bash script, which runs the VLC process with some arguments and then outputs it's ID to standart output:

```
cvlc $@ &
echo $!
```

Then I have following java code which runs the script and reads it's ID from stdin:

```java
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/path/to/script");
InputStream stdin = proc.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(stdin);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
String line = br.readLine();
if(line!=null) {
    lastPID = new Integer(line);
    System.out.println("Last vlc PID=" + lastPID);
}
```

When I want to stop streaming, I will kill process with corresponding ID:

```java
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("kill " + lastPID);
```

Is there any way to write equivalent script in Windows 7 (cmd.exe or Windows PowerShell)? Alternatively, is there a way to write pure (platform independent) java code which runs process, then gets it's ID and stops it?

Answer (score 1):

There is the way. But why don't you try to terminate the process using pure java API? User `process.destroy()`. It is exactly like `kill PID`.

To get process ID you can use WMI. Check out the following resource: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2006/06/01/how-can-i-find-the-process-id-associated-with-a-batch-file.aspx

You can run your process with some kind of identifier passed as additional parameter and then perform WMI `select from Win32_Process where ...` and put the criteria into the where clause. But again, you actually do not need this.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method: [How to get the PID of running application in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21601466/how-to-get-the-pid-of-running-application-in-windows/31563559#31563559)

Then call this using the PID:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /PID " + PID_To_Be_Killed);
```