# How to get the PID of running application in Windows?

Tags: java, windows, pid

I have here my code snippet:

```
 ArrayList<String> cmd_exec_installer = new ArrayList<String>();
 cmd_exec_installer.add("file.exe");
 Process proc = new ProcessBuilder(cmd_exec_installer).start();
```

What I want to do is to get the PID of the process started executing `file.exe`.

Is there a way to do that in Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15319947/get-pid-of-runtime-process-using-jni) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750470/how-to-get-pid-of-process-ive-just-started-within-java-program?rq=1).

Basically, there's no simple way to achieve the task, unless you use the [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) libraries or reflection, as suggested in the linked questions.

Comment: thank you! @alberto. i was able to get the PID of the main process but still it cannot kill the sub process of the main process. I'm still trying to look for a good solution or perhaps a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me perfectly on Windows 7:

```
//Imports
import com.sun.jna.*;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT;


private String getWindowsProcessId(Process proc) 
{
    if (proc.getClass().getName().equals("java.lang.Win32Process")
            || proc.getClass().getName().equals("java.lang.ProcessImpl")) {
        try {
            Field f = proc.getClass().getDeclaredField("handle");
            f.setAccessible(true);
            long handl = f.getLong(proc);
            Kernel32 kernel = Kernel32.INSTANCE;
            WinNT.HANDLE handle = new WinNT.HANDLE(); 

            handle.setPointer(Pointer.createConstant(handl));
            return Integer.toString(kernel.GetProcessId(handle)); 

        } catch (Throwable e) {
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Source: http://cnkmym.blogspot.com/2011/10/how-to-get-process-id-in-windows.html